# Is there anyway to do a GROUP BY and COUNT with GAE's search API?

Tags: google-app-engine, gae-search

I just started using GAE's search API and I'm looking for the equivalent of a SQL group by count statement. Does something like this currently exist?

Comment: No you have to write your own

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not what it's for at all. It's a full-text search API, and has no support for things like grouping or other relational concepts.

Comment: I just figured that since it returns number_found for a given search, that there might be some grouping mechanism to get multiple counts. More of a hope that anything else, but that makes sense.

Comment: What if i use `search.AtomField` or `search.NumberField`? Can I group by this fields? 
Or is there a way to find distinct documents?

Answer (score 0):

As @Daniel Roseman noted, GROUP BY does not apply for the full-text Search API.

On [Datastore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries) there is count (but it's very expensive) but no GROUP BY.

[Google CLoud SQ](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/)L: it's basically a managed MySql instance - both GROUP BY and COUNT are available.

[Google Big Query](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/) is a distributed on-demand map-reduce system with [SQL-like query language](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/query-reference). It has both GROUP BY and COUNT. They are both expensive as queries are charged by rows x columns scanned (no indexes exist). BQ is very powerful (and fast) but exporting data to it from GAE is tedious as there is no direct API.